# Listing .dll files using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script to list all the files with a specific extension (.dll) in this case. my script is working fine except i want to filter out all of those files which have microsoft's copyright. What approach should be taken ?

```
$Dir = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework -include *.dll -recurse | sort-object name | format-table name, directory -auto
$Dir
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter using `$_.VersionInfo.LegalCopyright` inside a `Where-Object`-statement. Ex:

```
$Dir = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework -include *.dll -recurse |
Where-Object { $_.VersionInfo.LegalCopyright -notmatch 'Microsoft' }
$Dir | sort-object name | format-table name, directory -auto
```

Never store data from `Format-Table` in a variable. It throws away the objects and returns unusable format-objects. Only use it when outputing to console or with ex. `| Out-String | Out-File ...` when saving to a file.

Comment: this worked for me. is there a way to print publisher's name in one of the table's column as well. ?

Comment: Use calculated properties. What do you mean by Publisher? use `$dir[0].VersionInfo | format-list *` to see the available properties. There is one called CompanyName if that's what your after. Ex: `$Dir | sort-object name | format-table name, directory, @{n="Publisher";e={ $_.VersionInfo.CompanyName }} -auto`

Comment: This is what i wanted thanks. Can you please tell me where do i read about @{n= ; e=} thing. What is it called ?

Comment: Read the comment above. :-) Calculates properties. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx

Comment: Thanks frode. That was very helpful. I never heard about this. Much appreciated.

Comment: I am able to fetch company name which is desired. In some cases there is no company name associated with the file. However if i manually check the details there is a copyright section. Is there a way to fetch that data ? if yes, that ll be really helpfull. I cant find it in versionInfo though.

Comment: What have you tried? I've already shown you how to access the copyright-text

Comment: I wanted something like $dir[0].versioninfo.legalcopyright. Comapany name is something which was not available in all the file's details.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. You already know the property to access, so what's the problem?

Comment: Nothing now. It is working fine now. Thanks Frode. Although i ll need help on another script i am working on. :) will post a question